# Sliding a sliding window "intelligently"?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, classification

In sliding window object detectors, is it possible to do object detection "intelligently"? For example, if a human is looking for a vehicle, they're not going to look into the sky for a car. But an object detector that uses a sliding window is going to slide the window across the entire image (including the sky) and run the object classifier on each window, resulting in a lot of wasted time. Are there are any techniques out there to make sure it only looks in reasonable places?

### Edit

I understand we'll have to look through everything at least once, but I wouldn't want to run a heavy complicated classifier on each window. A pre-classification classifier of sorts, perhaps?

Comment: Well at least he have to do it once, so he knows where is the sky. And what if the sky is covered by the object?

Comment: maybe look into saliency and human fixation studies. a naive method is to just run a simple edge filter, do normalization and sum the intensities. High intensities indicate more information and is worth checking with more computer time. This is depenedent on what type of classifier you are using. Haar cascades detector as implemented in opencv for example is already doing this step by way of rejectors each performing simple calculations akin to edge filters. Therefore not much performance gain can be expected.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered looking at saliency detection algorithms?  Saliency detection algorithms give you an indication of **where** in the image a human would most likely focus on.  A good example would be a human in an open field.  The sky would have low saliency while the human a high one.

Maybe put your image through a saliency detection algorithm first, then threshold and find regions of where to search instead of the entire image.

A great algorithm for this is by Stas Goferman: *Context-Aware Saliency Detection* - http://webee.technion.ac.il/~ayellet/Ps/10-Saliency.pdf.

There is also code here to get you started: https://sites.google.com/a/jyunfan.co.cc/site/opensource-1/contextsaliency

Unfortunately it is in MATLAB, and from your tag you want to look at Python.  However, there are many similarities between `numpy / scipy` and MATLAB so hopefully that will help you if you want to transcribe any code.

Check it out!

Comment: Thanks! I found this too: http://pdollar.wordpress.com/tag/representation/

Comment: Nice.  Thanks for the share!